# Best practice for a SQL-DB Connection module

Tags: c#, sql

I'm currently trying to improve the sql database module, since we have like 10 different ones that are all slightly different.

I'm wondering now what the best practise is to make this sql connection module as usable as possible. Mainly the search query:

Is

```
public List<ClassForDatatype> getData(String SQLStatement)
```

better than

```
public DataTable getData(String SQLStatement)?
```

In most places we just want to display the elements we got in a DataGrid. However we also want to use ToString to create an email.

What are your suggestions here?

Answer (score 0):

The first one is the better one.
The reason is that your DB layer should have nothing to do with your view layer.

EDIT:
You could use your second version, because it would be faster (less calls/conversions etc.). But if you decide at a certin point that you will switch from a DataGrid to something else, you have to rework a lot of code.

Comment: Yeah going by my gut feeling I would also have said the same. The error handling for a wrong cast should be in the class that uses the sql-connection object right?

Comment: sorry I meant an invalid cast like my SQL Statement only returns strings but the specified ClassForDatatype is also some integers

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, because when you have some kind of "model" you would use the correct types. So there should be no cast errors. But you could get cast problems when displaying your data (int in text fields etc.) but you also could create a view model for that. Depends all on the size of the application and the needed abstracion levels.